# Anyone having deep knowledge for angular 2 and socket.io with observer subscribe for given service

Tags: angular, socket.io

i am using of this code for receive (subscribe) MSG to socket in angular 2 with observer service but i have used in global application but it's created multiple time msgs.. on routeing another pages i created one chat-box component which opened global after open like Facebook chat-box.this condition coming on route times only..

```
  `get-messages() {
    let observable = new Observable(observer => {
      this.socket = io(this.url);
      this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
        observer.next(data);    
      });
      return () => {
        this.socket.disconnect();
      };  
    })     
    return observable;
   } `
```

Comment: Please, take some more time and make proper english sentences. We can't help you if we don't understand what you want.

Comment: do `observer.complete()` along with `this.socket.disconnect()`

Comment: It's not working..please help any one

Answer (score 0):

i am integrating trading view chart library where i can get live update api for bitcoin all coins data